# “Object doesn't support property or method 'ready'”

Tags: jquery-plugins, mootools

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'ready'
```

I am getting this error while using custom dropdown list with js mootools slider. I have downloaded js slider and custom dropdown and while trying to merge it, I am facing this error.

I have downloaded the js slider plugin from here:
http://landofcoder.com/index.php?option=com_jdownloads&Itemid=372&task=view.download&cid=6

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it ?

Comment: I bet you have conflicting problems between jQuery and Mootools. Search google for *jquery mootools conflict*. Good luck, and next time, try to use only JS library in your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure what you have mootool and jquery required. You can open Inspector in Google Chrome and type in console tab `MooTools` and `jQuery`.

This libraries has conflict on global variable `$`.

```
document.id('element_id') // Mootools' "$"
jQuery('selector or something') // jQuery's "$"
```

I hope in you situation this should help

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // initialize you code
});
```